# File Uploading Using Django

Tags: django, django-models, request

i'm new in django and i have a problem with Uploading File Please Help me!! :X

here is my view.py

> def uploadimg(request):
>
> try:
>
> ```
>    user = request.session['user']        
>
>    if request.method == 'POST':
>
>        form = User_image_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
>        #if form.is_valid():
>        usr_img = User_image(imgfile = request.FILES['imgfile'])
>        return HttpResponse("yes")
>        #usr_img.user = user
>        usr_img.save()
>        return HttpResponse("yees the first upload is right !! :X")
>    else:
>        return HttpResponse("Noooooo!!!")
> ```
>
> except:
>
> ```
>    pass
> ```

this is my form.py

> class User_image_form(forms.Form):
>
> ```
>    imgfile = forms.FileField()
> ```

and this is my models.py

> class User_image(models.Model):
>
> ```
>    imgfile = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'User-Image')
>    #user = models.ForeignKey(User_account)
> ```

and i have problem in view.py at line which

> usr_img = User_image(imgfile = request.FILES['imgfile'])

and it's never get to the

> return HttpResponse("Yes")

error:

> Exception Value: The view User.views.uploadimg didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Plz Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an exception, you are not returning an `HttpResponse` object. Hence the error.

use `form.is_valid()` to see if the form is valid. 
Something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = User_image_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        usr_img = User_image(imgfile = form.cleaned_data['imgfile'])
        usr_img.user = user
        usr_img.save()
        return HttpResponse("yees the first upload is right !! :X")
    else:
        print form.errors #for debugging purposes only. 

    return HttpResponse("Noooooo!!!")
```

Comment: i put the HttpResponse("yes") befor the error line and it was ok !

Comment: rather than enclosing the whole block in try..except, makeit as localized as possible. example put the `try..except` around exactly where the erro might occur.

Comment: is there a problem in     usr_img = User_image(imgfile = request.FILES['imgfile']) ???

Comment: just edited the answer. . Looks fine, but you might need to check validity

Comment: @karthikr if the form is not valid it will still not return `HttpResponse` You might want to decrease indent for inner `HttpResponse`

Comment: the form is not valid. !!?? why?? something wrong in forms.py??

Comment: You can print form.errors to see what is wrong in the form. check the edit.

Comment: thank you! something was wrong in template and request.FILES was empty  and the error was :  imgfile:this field is required !!! :X :-*